# In python, returning an object created in a function body makes a deep copy of it?

Tags: python, copy, return-value, deep-copy

I'll try to clarify:

For example, I make a function that locally creates a list, and return it. How does Python create the returned list that exist outside the function body ? Does it use "deepcopy" (or something similar) ?

```
In [50]: def create_list():
    ...:     sublist1 = [1,2,3]
    ...:     sublist2 = [4,5,6]
    ...:     list_of_lists=[sublist1,sublist1,sublist2]
    ...:     return list_of_lists
    ...: 

In [51]: l=create_list()

In [52]: l
Out[52]: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

In [53]: l[0].append(4)

In [54]: l
Out[54]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Here, the returned list `l` still contains the sublists. And `l[0]` and `l[1]` still reference the same sublist (which is normal Python behavior). So the list and its structure were copied.

And if I call once again `create_list()` :

```
In [55]: l2=create_list()

In [56]: l2
Out[56]: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

In [57]: l
Out[57]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
```

A new list `l2` has been created, but `l` is unaffected, which means it does exist outside the function, and its sublists are its own, not references to sublists that would still exist in the function body.

So my question : does Python used deepcopy or something similar to make `l` ?
Not matter what kind of object I return with a function, it will be unaffected by subsequent call to this function ?
(as long as the object was created locally in the function)

Do not hesitate to tell me if I'm not clear enough.
Thanks,

Comment: No but python does create new objects each time you run a function bar you pass a mutable default arg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the function the second time, the entire function is rerun - it has no memory along the lines of *"last time, `sublist1` was `[1, 2, 3]`"*.

You haven't *copied* the list `[1, 2, 3]`. You've *created* it twice.

---

Note that if you use a caching decorator like [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache), you'll get surprising results:

```
>>> @lru_cache()
... def create_list():
...     sublist1 = [1,2,3]
...     sublist2 = [4,5,6]
...     list_of_lists=[sublist1,sublist1,sublist2]
...     return list_of_lists
...
>>> l = create_list(); l
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> l[0].append(4); l
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> create_list()
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Because in this case, python does have a memory of the previous result, and returns the same object

Comment: I thought it might have memory of previous time, since something like `def f(l=[]):` keeps track between different calls to `f`. So the default parameters are constructed only once when the function is defined, but its local values are only constructed when it is called (and are thus different for each call) ?

Comment: @Yann: Bingo. Local values are constructed at function _call_ time, default arguments are constructed at function _definition/declaration_ time

Comment: About your example with `@lru_cache()`, I understand that it caches previous function calls, so during the second call, it sees that a first call was made with the same arguments (i.e. none), so simply return the value of the first call (which was modified in between by  `l[0].append(4)`) ? I just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: @Yann: Again, correct. Note the arguments were the empty tuple, `()`, not `None`.

Answer (score 4):

**This might not directly answer this question but should help clarify related concept.**

If you create a nested object inside a function and return it, the object will continue to exist. It would not go out of scope even though the function ended.

**Example Code**

```
class Some_Class (object):
    prop_x = None
    def __init__(self, prop_x ):
        self.prop_x = prop_x
    def __repr__(self):
        return "prop_x = "+repr (self.prop_x)

def fx ():
    dict_x = { "k1" : "v1" }
    print hex ( id (dict_x) )
    obj1 = Some_Class ( prop_x = dict_x )
    print hex ( id (obj1.prop_x) )
    print "obj1 is "+repr( obj1 )
    return obj1

recv_obj = fx ()

print "recv_obj is "+repr( recv_obj ) 
print hex ( id (recv_obj.prop_x) )
```

**Output**

```
0xdfaae0
0xdfaae0
obj1 is prop_x = {'k1': 'v1'}
recv_obj is prop_x = {'k1': 'v1'}
0xdfaae0
```

A dict, `dict_x`, is assigned to `prop_x` variable of a Class object `obj1`. The dict is not created again in memory but a `soft copy` takes place. `prop_x` points to the memory location of `dict_x`.

When you return object `obj1` at the end of this function, `dict_x` goes out of scope but the memory address used by it, `0xdfaae0`, is still pointed by `prop_x` in the returned object `recv_obj`. So, the dict values `{ "k1" : "v1" }` are preserved in memory.

Comment: `dict_x` address was `0x2ff5540`, `prop_x` address is `0x35c5540 `. How do you say `prop_x` points to the same object as `dict_x` *(in the heap)*? Can you please explain it, may be I am missing something..

Comment: @Shaharyar There was a typo in the memory address. The answer holds good. I have taken a fresh output of the same code and updated my answer. Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: Oh, I was actually sure I am being dumb to not understand it :) thanks anyway. Great example

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Python are pointers to objects. So a function would return a pointer to an object created in the function, obviating the need for copying return values.

Comment: I know, what I was wondering was if it returns a pointer to an object, why does it point to different things for different runs ? I thought that when a function was defined, its local variables were also defined (since it's the case for default arguments), meaning that `sublist` was always at the same address in the memory, but it was not the case.